# How do you force JSP to get re-compiled

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee

I'm trying out a new version of a web framework, and need to re-compile all my Jsps.

What is the easiest way to do this?

I'm using Weblogic (Oracle) 10.3.3, but we can use this question to collate methods to force recompiles for all servers here. Also I'm working on a dev box, so there no problem stoping/ starting the server, or deleting tmp directories.

Note: The most generic way I've found, is to update (touch) your jsp files.

```
find ./ -name '*.jsp' -exec touch {} \;
```

This however might not be very easy if you have a lot of files, and or are working on a non unix environement (As I am, and I can't install cygwin)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer my own question:

For Tomcat.
Deleting the following directory will cause all jsps to get recompiled.

```
${CATALINA_HOME}/work/Catalina/localhost/$WEBAPP
```

For Oracle Weblogic Server (10.3.3)
Deleting the following directory (on my server) will cause jsps in to get recompiled, e.g.

```
${DOMAIN_HOME}/servers/AdminServer/tmp/_WL_user/<WAR_Name>/lussfm/jsp_servlet/_jsp/
```

Answer (score 1):

What build environment are you using?

If you're using ant or maven, I would suggest seeing if there is a way to force a copy of the JSP files regardless of modified time.

Since you indicated you are using ANT for your build system, I would add a target to your build to use the [touch](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/touch.html) ant task. The documentation linked should point you in the right direction.

Comment: We are using Ant. It would be possible but I am using the actual source folder as the webapp, so there is no copying going on. I guess I'm looking for a directory to delete, or a adminGui type switch. I know for example in Tomcat you can delete the following directory

    ${CATALINA_HOME}/work/Catalina/locahost/$WEBAPP

Comment: I've updated my answer to indicate a possible solution that /should/ work on all platforms.